# How to uninstall other OS's using Ubuntu?

Tags: uninstall

Having found Mint better than Windows 7, and now finding Ubuntu 12.04 an even better experience, I would like to uninstall Mint from my triple-booted machine.  (Migrating my files to Ubuntu, of course.)  How to do this?

Follow-up: Is there a simple procedure for uninstalling Windows 7, while migrating files to Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: mint is offtopic on askubuntu. But you can format the partition with mint on it with gparted. FOr the remainder: mount the partitions and you can c/p data.

Comment: @Rinzwind  while Mint is off-topic, I don't believe this question truly is.  the OP wants to _remove_ Mint(and maybe Windows as well) and keep Ubuntu.  If a question about removing another OS and keeping Ubuntu is really off-topic, there are a lot of questions on askubutu about removing Windows and keeping Ubuntu that are off-topic as well.....

Comment: To help you in the future, install you home directory on a separate partition, this way you won't need to back up all you personal files when formatting.

Comment: This question should belong to the [Linux/Unix site](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), it has no direct connection to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

To migrate any files you may want to keep, you will need to mount the partitions and the copy the data over from one partition to the other.

The easiest way to Uninstall ANY operating system is with  [**OS-Uninstaller**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/os-uninstaller/)

The Ubuntu Wiki about it is [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller)

to install it, boot to Ubuntu and then do the following in the terminal...

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/os-uninstaller
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install -y os-uninstaller && os-uninstaller
```

This will install and run OS Uninstaller, just select the OS you want to remove...

[image]

then click **Apply** in the confirmation window.

[image]

The selected OS will be removed and your GRub(bootloader) files will be updated to remove the OS from the boot Menu

I would suggest that you remove OS Unistaller after you have used it to avoid any unfortunate removal mistakes in the future, You will likely not need it again soon and it is easy enough to reinstall if you need it again....